# Moment.js to get UTC time as date object instead of string

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, utc

I want to get the UTC time using `moment.utc()` as a date object instead of epoch or string (`moment.utc().format()` or using `.toISOString()`). `moment.utc().toDate()` returns my local time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the *.toDate* method: `moment().toDate()`. Date objects are UTC.

Comment: convert that string to a Date object

Comment: _“moment.utc().toDate() returns my local time”_ – no, it returns a Date object. When _output_ in a way that requires it to be converted into a string value, that might _display_ in your local time, yes.

Comment: @RobG ```var utc_date = moment().toDate();
  console.log('utc_date ' + utc_date);``` Output - Fri Jun 23 2017 14:10:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: @CBroe I just did a console.log. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Anjana—as CBroe says, you're seeing the string representation which (usually) uses the host offset to create a string. The built-in object is UTC. Try `moment().toDate().toISOString()`.

Comment: @RobG So if I have to use the date object directly(`moment().toDate()`) without checking for the representation, that would be the right UTC time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `moment().toDate()`. If you coerce the date to a string (e.g. by sending it to the console, alert, etc.), the built-in (implementation dependent) *toString* method will typically use the host timezone settings to generate a string, e.g.

```js
var m = moment().toDate();  // Equivalent to new Date()

console.log(m + '') // coerce to string uses built-in toString
console.log(m.toISOString()) // ISO 8601 string offset +0000
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Clearly he was asking for a Date object , not a string!

Comment: @JAN—see the very first statement of the answer, which produces a Date object.